# What if I know the result is an integer, but ghc is not so sure?

Tags: haskell

Let's say I have this piece of code:

```
demo::Integer -> Integer
demo x = x*(x+1)/2

main = do print $ demo 8
```

clearly, the result is an integer as either x or its successor is even.
Understandably the compiler only looks at `/` and says

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( debug.hs, debug.o )

debug.hs:2:17:
    No instance for (Fractional Integer) arising from a use of `/'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Fractional Integer)
    In the expression: x * (x + 1) / 2
    In an equation for `demo': demo x = x * (x + 1) / 2
```

But to my knowledge `Integer` is not part of `Fractional`.
How can I keep the signature `Integer -> Integer`?

Comment: You can't use `/` with Integers. Try ``demo x = x*(x+1) `div` 2``

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed! If you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Also remember that there is a difference between *mathematical numbers* and their implementation in programming languages. Just because you can mathematically proof that a certain expression is always an integer doesn't mean that when you try to compute it using a programming language you *actually* get an integer. That depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use the `/` function with `Integer`s. Use `div` instead if you want classic integer division.